# Wrapping a glibc function using the dynamic linker

Tags: c, gcc, wrapper, glibc, dynamic-linking

I am trying to wrap the GLIBC `fstat` function (it could be any other: it is just a proof of concept) by injecting my library to an executable. I do this by placing my library where the executable's `RPATH` is pointing with the name `libc.so.6`.

The source code of my library is the one below:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>



int fstat(int fd, struct stat *buf){

        typeof(fstat) *old_fstat;

        // Try with a printf...

        printf("HOOT! fstat wrapped!");

        old_fstat = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fstat");
        return (*old_fstat)(fd, buf);
}
```

I compile it with `--version-script` (to add symbol versioning) and statically link it to libgcc.

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c -o wrapperlib.o wrapperlib.c 
gcc -shared -static-libgcc -fPIC -Wl,-soname -Wl,libc.so.6 -Wl,--version-script=wrapperlib.map,-Bstatic -o libc.so.6 wrapperlib.o
```

With `wrapperlib.map` containing:

```
GLIBC_2.0 {
};
```

When I execute the target program my library gets loaded but I get the following error:

```
./target: relocation error: ./target: symbol __libc_start_main, version GLIBC_2.0 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

If I provide my own implementation of `__libc_start_main` I don't get this error (but it crashes, of course).

```
int __libc_start_main(int (*main) (int, char **, char **), int argc, char *argv, void (*init) (void), void (*fini) (void), void (*rtld_fini) (void), void *stack_end) {
        system("echo I am in __libc_start_main");
        printf("printf: I am in __libc_start_main");
        fflush(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is there a relocation error on `__libc_start_main` and not on `system`?

(By the way, the call to the `system` does work but the call to `printf` produces no output. Am I missing something obvious here?)

Thank you

Edit:
Running target with `LD_DEBUG=all` outputs this:
http://pastebin.com/iVVbwf6n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I [place] my library where the executable's `RPATH` is pointing with the name `libc.so.6`.

And therefore the process loads your library *instead of* GLIBC's `libc.so.6`.  <s>That is surely not what you want unless you're providing an *independent* implementation of at least *the entire C standard library*.</s>  That requires your library to provide an *independent* implementation of everything in `libc.so.6`, or else to dynamically load the real `libc`.  I see that you attempt to attain completeness by statically linking libgcc (I guess you mean using `-lstatic-libgcc`), but

1. that's the wrong library.  It provides functions to support GCC-compiled binaries, which may include wrappers or alternatives for some C-library functions, but it does not provide the C library itself.
2. even if you linked the C library statically (e.g. `-lc_nonshared`), the library you get that way will not include a dynamically loadable symbol by which you can access the wrapped function.  That's a direct consequence of the static linking.
3. your library is anyway not independent because it tries to wrap GLIBC's implementation of `fstat()`, which is unavailable to it.

> Why is there a relocation error on `__libc_start_main` and not on `system`?

There is a relocation error on `__libc_start_main` because that function is provided by the glibc's libc.so.6, but not by yours, nor by your binary itself or any other library dynamically linked to your binary.  *(See (1) above)*

If there is no relocation error for the `system` or `printf` functions, then it follows that either those are not external dynamic symbols in your binary, or they are satisfied by some other library dynamically linked to your binary.  (***Update:*** the linker debug information shows the former to be the case: those are not external symbols, by which I meant symbols for which no definition is provided; they are provided by your library, presumably as a result of linking in libgcc.) <s>The details don't really matter, as the point is that your strategy is totally unworkable.</s>  Consider using [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/426230/2402272) instead.

**Update:** an alternative might be to give your shared library a constructor function that `dlopen()`s the real `libc.so.6` with flag `RTLD_GLOBAL` enabled.  This way, your library does not have to provide a complete C library itself, but it does need to know how to find the real library.  That will certainly solve the problem of the wrapped function being unavailable in the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not use LD_PRELOAD because the whole point is to wrap a GLIBC function call with the sole use of the target's RPATH. Still, I don't see which other library might satisfy those symbols:  I have edited to include LD_DEBUG output.

Comment: @mr_sparxx, I have substantially revised and updated the answer after noticing your comment that you are statically linking libgcc, which I had previously overlooked.

Comment: Yes, I meant -lstatic-gcc (I have edited my post) and that was my misconception, I will try the path you have opened by your update.

Comment: Actually it is `-static-libgcc` but the purpose was the one you mentioned. Thank you.